# Why the interpreter shows that there should be a colon?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to find the key of the biggest number in the values of dictionary:

```
    def compare(dictionary):
    varb0 = 0
    for i in dictionary:
        if dictionary[i] >= varb0:
            sha = dictionary[i]
    for j in dictionary:
        if dictionary[j] = varb0:
            return j
```

but the interpreter report an error of lack of colon:
[the screensnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEmIN.jpg)

so, is there anyone who could tell me why this error occured? or any idea of better solution for my stupid question?

Comment: The first word of fifth line of the code should be varb0 which is nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `=` you are assigning a value to a variable.

If you use `==` you are comparing the values inside variables for equality.

Therefore:

```
def compare(dictionary):
    varb0 = 0
    for i in dictionary:
        if dictionary[i] >= varb0:
            sha = dictionary[i]
    for j in dictionary:
        if dictionary[j] == varb0:
            return j
```

Comment: @DawnZhang if the answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it.